# Unable to generate SIGNEDD APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to build a signed APK. After the Gradle building for 43 minutes, it failed with some random memory error.

```
Out of memory: Java heap space.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
<em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
```

I tried adding `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=1024m -Xmx1024m` in gradle.properties, still no luck.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=2048m -Xmx2048m`
if you have 2gb of ram that you can dedicate to the compile. If you have more, increase it to more than that. 256mb of ram isn't enough for your compile apparently.